# Navigate to location settings page by xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

User should navigate to location settings page by click on the button in xamarin forms app. How to do it?

Edit: i need the user to turn on location on their phones

Comment: you generally can't navigate directly to system settings pages

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This will be about as close as you can get: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/app-information?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#displaying-application-settings

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin provides access to hardware permissions through Xamarin Essentials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios

You can easily prompt the user for permissions in-app using the appropriate [checks and prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=ios#requesting-permissions).

For your specific scenario, you might want to use the "LocationWhenInUse" or "LocationAlways" permissions.